# How to create images for dynamic text using PHP?

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I want to create images for my dynamic text.
My problem is that I am reading folder name from some specific directory.
So folder name will be what ever but client wants that folder name should come as the images only.
So I thought that I will place one image with the same name as folder on any unique name.
But client don't want to create new images if they create a new folder. 
So how can I do this with PHP?
I need to use some specific background color for image and also want to use some specific font for the text in image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [imagefttext()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php) in the **examples** section

Answer (score 0):

From php.net:
http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```