# Displaying stats on image using PHP

Tags: php, image, statistics

I am building a basic membership application using PHP, it also has an affiliate program. What I am trying to achieve is to display the stats for example the joining date of a member via referral banners when that member promotes the site.

The banner or image will be same but the stats displayed will differ from member to member.

For example:

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/?a=details&id=1" target="_blank"><img src="mywebsite.com/?a=image&id=1"/></a>
```

I have seen at some websites that the banner or image shows stats but I could not understand that the `src` tag do not have an image format at the end yet it displays the image on webpage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create images for dynamic text using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271731/how-to-create-images-for-dynamic-text-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

thats actually a div tag with height and width and given a background image. then you can design and place your data to be shown on that div

Comment: I understood what you said but it has to be an image not a div with css. For example you can view the HYIP monitoring websites like how their monitoring image shows program status and other stats.

Comment: send me a link what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I have found an example please visit the link.

http://davidmonitor.com/adt/index.php?id=504

If you just scroll a bit you will find a textarea at left please view the code in it and help me.

Here is another link of same website as above, the image is same but the data shows on it is different. Check this:
http://davidmonitor.com/adt/index.php?id=500

Comment: have a look at this library www.libgd.org. i believe it will help you what you want to achieve [www.libgd.org](http://www.libgd.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate images dynamically with [PHP GD (manual link)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).